# How to add vCard to contact application via QR code in Android?

Tags: java, android, vcf-vcard

I have an application where part of the functionality is user will generate a QR code and other users can scan and get contact details and add to their contact directly.

So i am encoding vCard details in below format:

```
String str =
                "BEGIN:VCARD\n" +
                        "VERSION:3.0\r\n" +
                        "N:" + userDetailsModel.getLastName() + ";" + userDetailsModel.getFirstName() + ";;Mr;\r\n" +
                        "FN:" + "Mr." + userDetailsModel.getFirstName() + " " + userDetailsModel.getLastName() + "\r\n" +
                        "ORG:" + userDetailsModel.getCompany() + "\r\n" +
                        "TITLE:" + userDetailsModel.getDesignation() + "\r\n" +
                        "EMAIL:" + userDetailsModel.getEmail() + "\r\n" +
                        "TEL;CELL:" + userDetailsModel.getPhone() + "\r\n" +
                        "END:VCARD\r\n";
```

Then upon receiving this string after being scanned , i am writing this to a file and then starting an intent action with the file to open and add to contact.
Below is my code:

```
 VCard vCard = Ezvcard.parse(qrResultDataString).first();

                    writeToFile(qrResultDataString);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    File path = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "contactFile.vcf");

                    try {
                        VCardWriter writer = new VCardWriter(path, VCardVersion.V3_0);
                        writer.write(vCard);
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path.getPath());
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/x-vcard"); //storage path is path of your vcf file and vFile is name of that file.
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Ignore the EZvcard part.

As a result i am getting option to add to contact and when i select any contact app a toast is showing with text "couldn't import vCard".
I am not getting any error message in logcat either.
Please help.

Comment: Hi! How did you implement ezvard-android-mapper into your code with no gradle/jar availability? Do you have your code online somewhere that I could check out? Thanks!

Comment: btw, you miss `\r` after `BEGIN:VCARD`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you need

```
     //GENERATE QR
       private void generateQR(User user) {
           String str =
                   "BEGIN:VCARD\n" +
                           "VERSION:3.0\r\n" +
                           "N:" + user.getSurname() + ";" + user.getName() + ";;Mr;\r\n" +
                           "FN:" + "Mr." + user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname() + "\r\n" +
                           "EMAIL:" + user.getEmail() + "\r\n" +
                           "TEL;CELL:" + user.getPhone() +"\r\n" +
                           "END:VCARD\r\n";
   
           QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
           try {
               BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(str, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);
               int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
               int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
               Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
               for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                   for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                       bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
                   }
               }
               image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
   
           } catch (WriterException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I already solved it and it is exactly what u mentioned. If u scan the generated qr code,  add contact comes automatically.  I was under the impression that i needed to program the scan and add contact from my end. I was successful on doing that but i ended up doing a lot of unnecessary things.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and trying different thing i finally found the answer.
This was very silly.
First thing is i forgot to use the file provider given i was targeting API level 24 plus.
And other is i didn't use the below flag after using the provider.

```
 Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            ShareScreen.this,
                            "com.alphapublishing.digitalbusinesscard.provider",
                            path);
  intent.setDataAndType(uri,"text/x-vcard"); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Credit to this post : [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed/38858040#38858040)